# How to create an ethereum account using truffle ( not in the console mode )

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

i m using truffle for compiling and deploying a smart contract in ethereum and for that i need to create some account to interact with the smart contract .

the creation of the account is always made with the command line in truffle like this :

```
    truffle console
 web3.personal.newAccount('verystrongpassword')
web3.eth.getBalance('0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1')
web3.personal.unlockAccount('0x95a94979d86d9c32d1d2ab5ace2dcc8d1b446fa1', 'verystrongpassword', 15000)
```

is there a way that i can put this code in a script (javascript) and run it with truflle without the command line

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Truffle console **is** an interactive JavaScript console. Anything you can do in the console can be done in another JavaScript environment. The implementation details change depending on if you're running within a browser/Node environment and the Ethereum node provider you're connecting to.

It's a little tricky with web3js 0.20.x because the `web3.personal` library is not always available in your client for security reasons (it depends on if you're connecting to a local node via IPC or RPC and which APIs that node has enabled. See may the [Geth Management API documentation](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs) for details).

It's much easier if you're using [web3js 1.0.0](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html). In that version, they introduced functionality in `web3.eth.accounts` that allows you to create new accounts.